# Network drives in quick access without creating traps

Tags: windows-explorer

My question is similar to this one: [Deleting quick access links from disconnected network drive in Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/1086605/deleting-quick-access-links-from-disconnected-network-drive-in-explorer)

Except that I would rather not actually unpin them when disconnected. Otherwise, I would always have to repin them.

I just want them not to hang File Explorer when I mouse over them, creating "traps" that I have to avoid while dragging items.

[image: screenshot of file explorer hanging when an item is mouse-dragged over a disconnected network drive]

What solution would you recommend?

- Write a script to auto-reconnect them (when possible) on startup?
- Use a third-party file explorer?
- Train myself by muscle memory to drag from a window by the top or bottom instead of left edge?
- Abandon the idea of having network drives in the quick access sidebar?
- Something else?

Comment: So far I have been training myself by muscle memory to drag by the top or bottom. Undesired side effect: I find myself doing this with all windows, not just File Explorer, lowering my productivity by 0.7% (remembering that 76% of all statistics are made up on the spot)